# Chrome Extension: Displaying & Hiding Elements?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, styles

I'm currently trying to hide a button that is visible on a page, while displaying another one that is automatically hidden (both are on the page, I'm not adding new ones, just changing visibility).

This is how it looks like right now:

```
<div class="myAwesomeButtons">
     <button id="first_button" class="blue_button inset_button" style="">First</button>
     <button id="second_button" class="green_button inset_button" style="display: none;">Second</button> 
     <button id="third_button" class="other_button">Third</button>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to remove the first button, and remove the `style` attribute on the second button. How can I achieve this using JavaScript within a Chrome extension?

I already have my manifest.json file in order, but I'm not sure how to go about the rest.

This is what I've tried, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
function fixButtons() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("myAwesomeButtons")[0].style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementsByClassName("myAwesomeButtons")[1].style.visibility='visible';
}

fixButtons();
```

Comment: The buttons are actually `children` of the `myAwesomeButtons` class, not members.

Answer (score 0):

```
function fixButtons() {
  var buttonGroup = document.getElementsByClassName("myAwesomeButtons")[0].getElementsByTagName("button");
  buttonGroup[0].style.visibility='hidden';
  buttonGroup[1].style.visibility='visible';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the `display` and `visibility` properties.

I avoid using `getElementsByClass` when possible since it doesn't work with IE. I know this is a Chrome extension though, so it would work. However, since each button already has an ID, I would just use `getElementById`.

Try

```
function fixButtons() {
    var button1 = document.getElementById("first_button");
    button1.style.display= "none";
    var button2 = document.getElementById("second_button");
    button2.style.display= "inline";
}
```